# AddressBook taking 62 GB space by images

Tags: macos, mojave, storage

For whatever reason, AddressBook is taking up 62gb of space on my limited availability system of a Macbook Pro running Mojave. This is what the daisy disk looks like.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this and why is it doing it?

Almost all of the space is being taken up by "Images and I have no clue what these "images" could be, since it is files in the depths of my system. I don't want to just in discriminate remove them for fear of losing major functionality.

Could someone explain the function of this and how to clean it?

I found this on GitHub but don't know what it is really.

https://gist.github.com/niw/635904

Comment: There could be a lot of images. You can check it in the Finder. Turn off contacts in iCloud preferences (and all other contact accounts like gmail/ outlook) and if the space goes down, turn them back on.

Comment: Unfortunately that did nothing. It's all coming from one place. 

AddressBook>Sources>[random hash]>images 

I have iCloud photo storage turned on, so they shouldn't be saving to my local, if that's what that is.....

Can anyone help?

Cheers.